# Line interpolation order in a radar plot in VEGA

Tags: powerbi, visualization, powerbi-desktop, vega, deneb

I am trying to design a radar plot to allow the end-user to compare different products. However, I am facing a bit of an issue with the interpolation of lines.  Vega offers some standard interpolation techniques, but I am wondering if there is a way to to the data points connect points either in a clockwise or counter-clockwise manner.  See the problem below.

[image]

What I would like.

[image]

For a sour taste, the orange line should follow the red line and not jump over to waffle pancake aroma.

Here is the code that generates this: category = products, key =aroma.

```
{
  "width": 600,
  "height": 400,
  "padding": {
    "left": 100,
    "top": 100,
    "bottom": 50
  },
  "autosize": {"type": "none", "contains": "padding"},

  "signals": [
    {"name": "radius", "update": "(width / 3.1)-18"}
  ],

  "data": [
    {
      "name": "dataset"},
    {
      "name": "keys",
      "source": "dataset",
      "transform": [
        {
          "type": "aggregate",
          "groupby": ["key"]
        },
        {
          "type": "window",
          "sort": {"field": "key"},
          "frame": [null, null]
        }
      ]
    }
  ],

  "scales": [
    {
      "name": "angular",
      "type": "point",
      "range": {"signal": "[-PI, PI]"},
      "padding": 0.5,
      "domain": {
        "data": "dataset",
        "field": "key"
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "radial",
      "type": "linear",
      "range": {"signal": "[0, radius]"},
      "zero": true,
      "nice": false,
      "domain": {
        "data": "dataset",
        "field": "value"
      },
      "domainMin": 0
    },
    {
      "name": "color",
      "type": "ordinal",
      "domain": {"data": "dataset", "field": "category"},
      "range": {"scheme": "category10"}
    }
  ],
  
  "axes": [
    { 
    "orient": "top",
    "scale": "radial",
    "domainWidth": 0.2,
    "tickCount": 4,
    "tickWidth": 0.2,
    "labelFlush": false,
    "labelFontSize": 9,
    "labelColor": "gray"
    }
  ],

  "encode": {
    "enter": {
      "x": {"signal": "radius"},
      "y": {"signal": "radius"}
    }
  },
  "marks": [
    {
      "type": "group",
      "name": "categories",
      "zindex": 1,
      "from": {
        "facet": {"data": "dataset", "name": "facet", "groupby": ["category"]}
      },
      "marks": [
        {
          "type": "line",
          "name": "category-line",
          "from": {"data": "facet"},
          "encode": {
            "enter": {
              "interpolate": {"value": "linear-closed"},
              "x": {"signal": "scale('radial', datum.value__highlight) * cos(scale('angular', datum.key))"},
              "y": {"signal": "scale('radial', datum.value__highlight) * sin(scale('angular', datum.key))"},
              "stroke": {"scale": "color", "field": "category"},
              "strokeWidth": {"value": 1},
              "fill": {"scale": "color", "field": "category"},
              "fillOpacity": {"value": 0.2}
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "type": "line",
          "name": "category-line-highlighted",
          "from": {"data": "facet"},
          "encode": {
            "enter": {
              "interpolate": {"value": "linear-closed"},
              "x": {"signal": "scale('radial', datum.value__highlight) * cos(scale('angular', datum.key))"},
              "y": {"signal": "scale('radial', datum.value__highlight) * sin(scale('angular', datum.key))"},
              "stroke": {"scale": "color", "field": "category"},
              "strokeWidth": {"value": 1},
              "fill": [
                {
                  "test": "datum.__selected__ == 'on'",
                  "scale": "color", 
                  "field": "category",
                  "value": 0
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "type": "symbol",
          "name": "symbol-category",
          "from": {"data": "facet"},
          "encode": {
            "enter": {
              "interpolate": {"value": "linear-closed"},
              "x": {"signal": "scale('radial', datum.value) * cos(scale('angular', datum.key))"},
              "y": {"signal": "scale('radial', datum.value) * sin(scale('angular', datum.key))"},
              "fill": {"scale": "color", "field": "category"},
              "fillOpacity": {"value": 0.5},
              "size": {"value": 30}
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "type": "text",
          "name": "value-text",
          "from": {"data": "category-line"},
          "encode": {
            "enter": {
              "x": {"signal": "datum.x"},
              "y": {"signal": "datum.y"},
              "text": {"signal": "datum.datum.value"},
              "align": {"value": "center"},
              "baseline": {"value": "middle"},
              "fill": {"value": "black"},
              "fillOpacity": { "value": 0}
              
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "type": "rule",
      "name": "radial-grid",
      "from": {"data": "keys"},
      "zindex": 0,
      "encode": {
        "enter": {
          "x": {"value": 0},
          "y": {"value": 0},
          "x2": {"signal": "radius * cos(scale('angular', datum.key))"},
          "y2": {"signal": "radius * sin(scale('angular', datum.key))"},
          "stroke": {"value": "lightgray"},
          "strokeWidth": {"value": 0.5}
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "text",
      "name": "key-label",
      "from": {"data": "keys"},
      "zindex": 1,
      "encode": {
        "enter": {
          "x": {"signal": "(radius + 5) * cos(scale('angular', datum.key))"},
          "y": {"signal": "(radius + 5) * sin(scale('angular', datum.key))"},
          "text": {"field": "key"},
          "align": [
            {
              "test": "abs(scale('angular', datum.key)) > PI / 2",
              "value": "right"
            },
            {
              "value": "left"
            }
          ],
          "baseline": [
            {
              "test": "scale('angular', datum.key) > 0", "value": "top"
            },
            {
              "test": "scale('angular', datum.key) == 0", "value": "middle"
            },
            {
              "value": "bottom"
            }
          ],
          "fill": {"value": "black"},
          "fontWeight": {"value": "bold"}
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "line",
      "name": "outer-line",
      "from": {"data": "radial-grid"},
      "encode": {
        "enter": {
          "interpolate": {"value": "linear-closed"},
          "x": {"field": "x2"},
          "y": {"field": "y2"},
          "stroke": {"value": "lightgray"},
          "strokeWidth": {"value": 1}
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "legends": [
    {
      "orient": "none",
      "legendX": 290,
      "legendY": -170,
      "fill": "color"}
  ]
}
```

pbix: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1mi04vdyQTkhxzqd3zKtPidtvUR3OV__W/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I don't fully understand your problem but there is a faceted spider chart here which I created with some code that might help you. https://github.com/PBI-David/Deneb-Showcase

Comment: Thanks for the link! Very nice plots . I'll clarify. Each product can have a different set of aromas underlying the data. It's not always consistent as it would for the radar plot you show in examples (it follows saturates, carbs, sugars ..) In my case, e.g., the blue product does not have waffle aroma. This leads the the axes being different per product. The linear interpolation of the areas is following the same rules for both products (following the aggregate sum of value). I want each line constructed clockwise to avoid jumping over the axis for each aroma

Comment: I added a new image to exemplify better what I want.

Comment: I'll remove my solution so someone else is encouraged to answer as I still don't full understand the requirements I'm afraid.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to help me. I'm not sure how to explain myself better than what I have.